# React & Redux: preserving application state when navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am very new to React. I'm using Redux to manage application state. I have 2 components. One component modifies a part of the application state and the other component displays this change. This works fine when both components are on the same page.

However, when i tried to put the components at separate URLs using react-router-dom (4.0.0) so that submitting the form on one component takes you to the page/different url where you see the second component. But the second component now no longer sees the application state modification made by the first component.

How do you fix this? Is there a sample app I could look at that achieves this? Please help because I just cannot figure out why the application state isn't being preserved during navigation!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Without seeing how you've built the page it's impossible to say anything

Comment: does MapStateToProps ring a bell? Container components maybe?
Plz post a sample ...

Comment: The problem was that I was using anchor tags (<a href="/some/path">) rather thanLink component (<Link to="/some/path">) so it was circumventing state management! Simple fix :)